# QGIS Trace Tool; Error

Tags: qgis, trace

I have installed the traceDigitize tool from the experimental repository in QGIS 1.9.0 Lisboa. My understanding of the tool is that you have to:

1. Add 2 layers to QGIS Desktop. My empty shapefile to which I will edit and a polygon file of an object I want to trace.
2. Set Snapping Options on the polygon file
3. Activate the 'trace Edit' tool and move my cursor to the polygon I created until it snaps
4. Hold ctrl button and begin tracing.

It seems to be tracing along the polygon, but when I right click to end the edit I get an error message:

[image]
[image]

I'm not sure what this means. I know this plugin is experimental, but the one thread I found about this tool implies it works. Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This plugin does not work with QGIS 1.9 (master) since the srs() method has been removed and replaced by the crs() method.

See the API documentation: http://doc.qgis.org/api/classQgsMapLayer.html

Comment: Is the method still relatively the same? Could I just change the call from layers.srs() to layers.crs()?

Comment: Sure, give it a try. It returns the same object as the previous srs() method.

Comment: Hmmm...it doesn't look like either one of those modules are installed. I'm using the OSGEO4w installer to install QGIS 1.9. Is there a specific library I should be installing? I can't figure out which one it is when I scroll through all the libs.

Comment: Edit line 282 in vertexTracerTool.py, changing layerEPSG = layer.srs().epsq() to layerEPSG= layer.crs().epsg(). The path to it is shown in your screenshots posted with your original question

Comment: Thanks for helping. That's the update I made. It's now telling me that 'QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem' object has no attribute 'epsg'. Any idea if they replaced/renamed this object as well in the crs() Method?

Comment: Yes, it has been replaced by authid().

Comment: Is there anyway of determining which objects/functions have been replaced/updated/removed? Like how do you know this? :) I'm running into 'QgsFeature' object has no attribute 'addAttribute', so I had a look in the QgsFeature C++ file and i see setAttribute and deleteAttribute, but no AddAttribute, which i am expecting because of the error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8304/discussion-between-gsherman-and-mike)